# WPF Animation Completed Event in ControlTemplate

Tags: wpf, events, animation, controltemplate

In my WPF application, I have the standard Generic.xaml file, which contains a style for my custom class, **Frost**.

I need to find a way to hook up the Completed event of one of the animations to my custom **Frost** class, I cannot do it at runtime because it complains at me that i need to set IsFrozen to false which I do not want to do (because of performance).

How can I hook up events to the TargetType of the control template?

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Controls:Frost}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Controls:Frost}">
                    <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                        <Storyboard x:Key="OnEndFrost">
                            <DoubleAnimation Name="fadeOutFrostAnimation"
                                             BeginTime="00:00:00" 
                                             Duration="00:00:02"
                                             Storyboard.TargetName="frostElement" 
                                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)"
                                             To="0">
                            </DoubleAnimation>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </ControlTemplate.Resources>
                    <Grid>
                        <MediaElement x:Name="frostElement" 
                                     LoadedBehavior="Manual"
                                     Width="1172" 
                                     Height="286.917" 
                                     Source="{TemplateBinding SourceUri}"
                                     ScrubbingEnabled="True">
                            <MediaElement.Effect>
                                <eff:ChromaKeyAlphaEffect InputColor="#FF0E425E" Tolerance="0.1" />
                            </MediaElement.Effect>
                        </MediaElement>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Controls:Frost.EndFrost">
                            <BeginStoryboard x:Name="OnEndFrost_BeginStoryboard" Storyboard="{StaticResource OnEndFrost}"/>
                        </EventTrigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Comment: " I cannot do it at runtime because it complains at me that i need to set IsFrozen to false which I do not want to do (because of performance)."

Frozen objects offer better performance, so I'm not sure what you mean by that.

Comment: frozen objects do not make as munch of a memory footprint and are thread safe... which is also important, correct me if Im wrong of course

Comment: That's correct, but you seem to be saying that you *don't* want to freeze your objects for performance reasons...? Freezing would improve performance AND let you hook the event.

Comment: I may have miss lead you, but you cannot add an event if its frozen, i dont want to un-freeze it because it performs better frozen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a custom animation and add an eventhandler to it or use a command as dependency property. For a codeproject example of a custom animation look at [this link](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/GridLengthAnimation.aspx).

Comment: I might have to do that I think